# when i click anywhere in HTML webpage i got the ID of that tag using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I want to get the id of `Html` tag who is clicked by the user in entire web Page using `Jquery`. I tried but they are only for particular tag I have to pass in the function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("p").click(function(){
        alert($(this).attr("id"));
    });
});
```

Comment: it can be any tag so how i do that tell  me

Comment: You mean any tag?

Comment: You can do this using `$(document).on('click','*', function(){ /* Your code */ });`.

Comment: @ShahajiDeshmukh yeah any tag in body

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `$(document).on('click','*', function(){})`. It will listen `click` event on all the elements of the HTML page then you can check if the clicked element has `id` or not and then use that `id` value.

```js
$(document).on('click','*', function(){
  if(this.id){
    console.log(this.id);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='divId'>sample1</div>
<p id='pId'>some p content</p>
<input id='textid' />sample1
```